# servlet database connection

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

Hello everyone i am developing simple jsp file which takes some info from students like name,gender,skills etc and i am directing it to servlet and given database connections her.But when i run the code its not connecting to db. Can some one please help me out. Here is my servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection con=null;
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName="student_db";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "admin";


    String bttn_value = request.getParameter("submit");
    if(bttn_value.equalsIgnoreCase("submit"))
    {
        String name = request.getParameter("fname");

        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String skill ="";
        System.out.println("2222222222");
        String skills[]= request.getParameterValues("skill");
        for(int i=0;i<skills.length;i++)
        {
            skill +=skills[i]+",";
        }
        String addr=request.getParameter("adname");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        Statement stmt;

    try
    {
        System.out.println("444444444444");
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        System.out.println("333333333");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, username,
                password);

        System.out.print("Connected to database");
        String query1= "insert into student values  name='"
             +name +"',gender='"+gender+ "',skills='"+skill + "',addname='" 
             +addr +"',country='" +country +"'";
        stmt =con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
        out.print("<br>");
        response.sendRedirect("std.jsp");
        con.close();
        System.out.print("Disconnected from DB");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("123456");

    }
```

and here is my console
[image]

and the output what i am getting

[image]

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not need to create a new instance to register the driver.  `Class.forName(driver);` will suffice.

```
try
{
    System.out.println("444444444444");
    Class.forName(driver);
    System.out.println("333333333");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, username,
            password);

    System.out.print("Connected to database");
    String query1= "insert into student values  name='"
         +name +"',gender='"+gender+ "',skills='"+skill + "',addname='" 
         +addr +"',country='" +country +"'";
    stmt =con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
    out.print("<br>");
    response.sendRedirect("std.jsp");
    con.close();
    System.out.print("Disconnected from DB");

}
```

Also make sure the MySql JDBC driver is in your classpath.  You can download the jar or pull it in from maven.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

[Direct Download](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.9/mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar)

To import the jar, first download the jar file and place it within your file system, preferably within your project.

1. In Eclipse right click your project and select properties, then
   `Java Build Path`.
2. Next click the `Libraries` tab and click Add JARs (if .jar is in
   your project) or Add External Jars (if .jar is outside).
3. Find the jar file and click OK.

[image]

To get more useful debugging information, try printing the stacktrace in your catch, this can be removed once the problem is resolved.  I suspect it will tell you that it cannot find the mysql driver.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("123456");

}
```

If your issue is still not resolved, post this stacktrace with your question.

Comment: hi Kevin i have given the same as Class.forName(driver); also printed the stack trace its just showing                     2222222222
444444444444
123456                                                              and nothing else..

Comment: @Ritz have you added the MySQL database driver?

Comment: @Ritz answer updated.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hi do i need to Add "mysql-connector-java-5.1.9" as external jar??

Comment: It depends, if you saved it outside your project you need to use external jar.  If you saved the jar file within your project you can use add jar.  What I mean by inside or outside your project is if it is inside or outside the folder that contains your project.